# How to connect a storyboard button to a method in a different viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboard

My storyboard has a viewController NEWvc. It needs to call a bunch of methods in viewController OLDvc.

Initially, I added OLDvc as a property on NEWvc, and made methods on the NEWvc that would call selectors on the OLDvc. There must be a better way to directly link buttons in my storyboard to the OLDvc.

I can add an Object and turn it into an instance of OLDvc, but I need it to be the already existing instance, not a new one. I need a reference to the instance of OLDvc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a protocol with methods that the newVC will call on the oldVC:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
- (void)doSomethingOnOldVC;
@end
```

Then you make your oldVC implement the required methods:

```
@interface OldVC : UIViewControler <MyProtocol>
@end

@implementation OldVC
- (void)doSomethingOnOldVC
{
  NSLog(@"Something happened.");
}
```

When you show your newVC, you should provide and instance of oldVC to it and store it as a weak property:

```
@interface NewVC : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyProtocol> myDelegate;
@end
...
```

In oldVC:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  NewVC *newVC = sender.destinationViewController;
  newVC.myDelegate = self;
}
```

You can then call the delegate methods from any place in newVC.

Comment: This is exactly what I did at first. "Initially, I added OldVC as a property on NewVC, and made methods on the NewVC that would call selectors on the OldVC." I am asking is there a better way to link the buttons directly to the OldVC methods, such as by adding it as a reference in the storyboard?

Comment: So that I don't have to define new methods on each VC for each already existing method in OldVC.

Comment: @Bob What exactly is wrong about this method? You are not depending on a concrete instance of your OldVC class, which means you can easily swap myDelegate for a mock controller when you do your tests. If you link your buttons directly to the OldVC (which cannot be done as far as I know), you create unnecessary coupling which will make code support and refactoring more difficult in the long run.

Comment: Because I'm basically duplicating each method in OldVC in order to make this happen

Comment: @Bob Applying the same logic, you duplicate each publicly visible method, because it is declared in a .h file and implemented in a .m file. Additional levels of indirection are not always a bad thing. Why would you need to call a method on a ViewController that is not visible, anyway? It controls the view, but you don't have the view - there appears to be something wrong with the architecture (probably OldVC manages the model layer as well)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly i want to tell that naming a ViewController as NEWvc doesn't following any apple coding standards. Is can be NewVC for better readability.

Make them class methods that you want to call from another ViewController.

Then Invoke using class name

**Creating Class method**

```
Replace - with + prefix to your methods
```

**Example call**

```
[ClassName yourMethod];
```

Comment: But they need to use the existing instance of OldVC. Why would I make them class methods?

Comment: It is existing instance.. but you're making it as' class method